# android to leopard board communication

Tags: android

I have an android xoom and a leopard board dm365 and I would like to stream images from the board to the tablet at a rate as close to real time as possible. The leopard board has a serial, ethernet, and microusb connection on it and can probobly do bluetooth with enough work. How should they connect and which libraries should I use in the android end to talk to the leopard biard,.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which camera you have connected to the Leopardboard, LeopardImaging may have a firmware image that will turn the board into a USB webcam. When I connected a LeopardBoard with a MT9V034 camera to my PC, the video latency wasn't too bad.

I don't have a Xoom, but I don't remember seeing any support for connecting USB webcams to Android devices. If you just need images, it may be easiest to program the LeopardBoard to save the current image from the camera to a file every second or so, and then to run a web server to serve the image up to the Xoom over Ethernet.

Comment: That's probably one of the top three or so things I'm considering doing. Hopefully transfer rates could be good enough using this method.